# Define a relation $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ iff $b−a = d−c$. Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

Tags: equivalence-relations

In order to be an equivalence relation, it has to be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

Comment: Adapt https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4044792/589

Comment: Please show us your working or let us know what is causing you a problem if you want help/explanations

Comment: So.... show it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

Comment: So do you know what reflexive, symmetric and transitive mean.  Can you write the conditions in terms of the writing $b-a=d-c$?  That is Reflixive $\implies$ for any $(a,b)$ that $(a,b)\sim(a,b)\implies b-a = b-a$.  Can you always say that $b-a = b=a$.  If you can actually write out these sentences is it *literally* impossible not to prove it is an equivalence relationship.  Literally.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! In a sense, reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity are all "inherited" from the respective properties of equality (via which your relation is defined). In fact, it's not hard to prove the following generalization of your exercise: for any function $f$ the relation defined as $a\sim b$ if and only if $f(a) = f(b)$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Thank all so much! Was a bit confuse on the transitive point, I will be clearer next question. Took this from book word for word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflexivity:
We need $\forall (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2, (a,b) \sim (a,b)$, and we have $(a,b) \sim (a,b) \Leftrightarrow b - a = b - a$, which is true.

Symmetry:
We need $\forall (a,b), (c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^2, (a,b) \sim (c,d) \Rightarrow (c,d) \sim (a,b)$, and we have $(a,b) \sim (c,d) \Leftrightarrow b - a = d - c \Leftrightarrow d - c = b - a \Leftrightarrow (c,d) \sim (a,b)$.

Transitivity: We need $\forall (a,b), (c,d), (e,f) \in \mathbb{R}^2, \Big(\big((a,b) \sim (c,d)\big) \; \cap \big((c,d) \sim (e,f)\big)\Big) \Rightarrow \big((a,b) \sim (e,f)\big)$, and we have $(b - a = d - c) \cap (d - c = f - e) \Rightarrow b - a = f - e \Rightarrow (a,b) \sim (e,f)$

Comment: Thank you!! very clear now

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

So do you know what reflexive, symmetric and transitive mean?

Can you write the conditions in terms of the writing $b-a=d-c$?

Example: Reflixive $\implies$ for any $(a,b)$ that $(a,b)\sim(a,b)\implies b-a = b-a$.

Can you always say that $b-a = b-a$?[1]

DO the same for the definitions of symmetric and transitive.

If you can actually write out these sentences is it literally impossible *not* to prove it is an equivalence relationship[2].  Literally.

.....

[1]  Hint: Yes you can.  Everything is equal to itself so $b-a = b-a$.

[2]  It is *impossible* not to prove it.  You'll end up having to make claims like:  "$K = K;$" and "if $K = J$ then $J=K; $" or "If $K = J$ and $J = L$ then $K = L$" and, literally, you can't *not* have those be true.